# psycopg2 passing in table name

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have the following query

```
table = "#temp_table"
cursor.execute("""select * from %s as a """, (table))
```

I keep getting a syntax error at the from stement. Why will this not work?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: syntax error near from '#temp_table'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving this error because the arguments passed into the second argument, `(table)` (which really should be `(table,)`), are escaped in the SQL statement that is run.

In this example, the `select * from %s as a` is transformed into `select * from '#temp_table' as a` which is an error. To correctly insert a table name, you need to format the SQL statement string directly like so:

```
query = 'select * from "{}" as a'.format(table)
cursor.execute(query)
```

You should be very careful about what data you insert into the query this way because it's highly susceptible to SQL-injection exploits. Do not use this with untrusted data.

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy just explicitly put it into the sql statement instead of passing into the args parameter

Comment: so just like "select * from #temp_table as a"? the reason I wanted to pass this in as a variable is because I have a lot of queries that will be exactly the same except pulling from different tables. I wanted a way to be able to loop through them and just change the table name.

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy, please see the edit. You can format the `query` in the loop.